# Video rotation always wrong by using AndroidCameraMediaSourceConfiguration (AWS)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

In KinesisVideoClient for creating media source by using AndroidCameraMediaSourceConfiguration. it has camera orientation option but i doesnt work -- Streaming video getting rotated

withCameraOrientation(-90) -- it has default value -- i am trying to change the angle variation but getting the rotation wrong always

Comment: Related issue reported here :https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/854